# cross join by date in mysql

Tags: mysql, cross-join

I want to cross join (self join?) by date. For example:

If I got a table like:

```
Date   Number    
0307   A    
0307   B    
0328   C    
0401   A    
0401   B    
0519   A    
0519   C
```

what I want after cross join is:

```
Date    Number  Number        
0307    A       A    
0307    A       B    
0307    B       A    
0307    B       B    
0328    C       C    
0401    A       A    
0401    A       B    
0401    B       A    
0401    B       B    
0519    A       A    
0519    A       C    
0519    C       A    
0519    C       C
```

What should I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a normal inner join:

```
SELECT t.date,t.number,s.number
FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN YourTable s
 ON(t.date = s.date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl t1 INNER JOIN tbl t2 USING(`Date`);
```

Comment: Thats the same answer as mine ,you only used USING instead of ON clause.